# What is the best approach while pooling data from DB and query DB again to fetch additional information?

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-jdbc

The spring boot application that I am working on

1. pools 1000 messages from table X [ This table X is populated by another service s1]
2. From each message get the account number and query table Y to get additional information about account.

I am using spring integrating to pool messages from table X and reading additional information for account, I am planning to use Spring JDBC.

We are expecting about 10k messages very day.

Is above approach, to query table Y for each message, a good approach ?

Answer (score 0):

No, that indeed not. If all of that data is in the same database, consider to write a proper `SELECT` to join those tables in a single query performed by that source polling channel adapter.

Another approach is to implement a stored procedure which will do that job for you and will return the whole needed data: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html#stored-procedures.

Although if the memory for that number of records to handle at once is a limit in your environment or you don't care how fast all of them are processed, then indeed an integration flow with parallel processing of splitted polling result is OK. For that goal you can use a `JdbcOutboundGateway` as a service in your flow instead of playing with plain `JdbcTemplate`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-outbound-gateway